# Why does mongoose throw $strLenCP requires a string argument, found: null after using $exists

Tags: mongoose

I am trying to query by the string count of the property `bvn`, and since I was aware some value of bvn might be null i added the line

```
'bvn': { '$exist': true }
```

the complete line is this:

```
    await this.find({$or: [
        {'bvn': null},
        {
          'bvn': { '$exist': true },
          '$expr': { '$gt': [ { '$strLenCP': '$bvn' }, 11 ] }
        }
    ]
  }).exec()
```

but I am still met with the error:

```
MongoError: $strLenCP requires a string argument, found: null
```

Answer (score 1):

You are currently testing for the field "bvn" to exist, but it might exist like this:
{bvn:null}
The problem is that strLenCP requires a string, but NULL is not a string.
Mongo actually tells you exactly that:

> MongoError: $strLenCP requires a string argument, found: null

So you need to filter out NULL content in your pipeline before(!) you do the strLenCP.

Please try like this:

```
await this.find({$or: [
        {'bvn': null},
        {
          'bvn': { '$exist': true },
          'bvn' : { '$ne'  => null },
          '$expr': { '$gt': [ { '$strLenCP': '$bvn' }, 11 ] }
        }
     ]
 }).exec()
```

Comment: `$exist` operator should be `$exists` with an `s`.